# AgGrid upgrade from v25 to v29 breaks the navigation (scroll and performance)

Tags: ag-grid, upgrade, ag-grid-react

I have a React application with AgGrid (enterprise) v25. I'm trying to upgrade it to v29. I went through all breaking changes and fixed them up in my app. The data is loaded as in the v25. After that the scroll starts lagging, I can't move the scroll vertically or horizontally. Even when I clear the data, once some data is loaded, the grid goes crazy.

Of course it's not a simple application, we're using Redux and a lot of logic layers between the data and the grid. I've already checked if there are unwanted rerenders. But everything is going fine.

Our last performance improvement was to change the way we set the data in the grid, instead of using props (rowData) we are setting through the `gridApi.setRowData` method. But this had no impact on the upgrade.

I'm wondering if there's something we're missing from the docs, because even with 500 rows of data the grid is messed up.